# How is C# event handling implemented?

Tags: c#, event-handling

When you update `DataGridView.DataSource` using the assignment operator, the `DataSourceChanged` event handler is called. You can't overload assignment op in C#, so how does the event handler get called internally?

```
public void foo(){
    this.dataGridView.DataSourceChanged += new EventHandler(bar);
    this.dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
}

//this handler is called after datasource changes
private void bar(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

Comment: Is this a problem you're having or a general question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DataSource` is implemented as a property.

```
private object _dataSource;
public object DataSource {
    get
    {
        return _dataSource;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _dataSource) {
            _dataSource = value;
            UpdateTheDataGridView();
            RaiseTheDataSourceChangedEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

A read/write property is a set of two methods, which are automatically called, when you access the property; `set` when you assign a value, `get` when you read the property.

Note also, that a change is only registered if you assign a data source something different. This means that you cannot refresh the grid by re-assigning the same data source.

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
dgv.DataSource = list;

list.Add("d");
dgv.DataSource = list; // Does not work.
```

Workaround:

```
list.Add("d");
dgv.DataSource = null; // <== this does the trick.
dgv.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 6):

It's up to the event *exactly* what it does, but I think of events as like properties - except instead of a getter and a setter, you have `add` and `remove` actions, each of which take the delegate to subscribe or unsubscribe to/from the event.

A *field-like* event in C# implements the event using a field for a delegate, and fixed add/remove implementations - a bit like an automatically implemented property. But you can do whatever you like in an `add` or `remove` handler.

See my [article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

As for the data source itself - that's not assigning a *field* - it's assigning to a *property*, so again, that can do whatever it wants to, including raising the `DataSourceChanged` event.

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking. If you're asking how the property setter can do something: a property setter is a method. It works like any other method. In this case, when the property setter is called it checks to see if it needs to raise the event, and if it does, then it raises the event.

If you're asking how the event itself is implemented, Jon's article is of course excellent. If you are looking for additional technical analysis of how events are implemented in C#, and how the implementation has changed over time, see Chris Burrows' blog articles on the topic:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/tags/events/

Start from the bottom.

Chris was the developer who designed and implemented a lot of the changes to the compiler's semantic analysis and code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Datasource is a property and the event handler is called in the set.

You can use ilspy to see how this is actually implemented.

Answer (score -1):

The event handler gets called internally because the class providing the event, in this case `DataGridView` explicitly fires the event at some point within it's code.  The property setter for the `DataSource` sounds like an appropriate place to fire this particular event, although I didn't look int he source code to verify exactly.

I'd suggest looking up a simple tutorial on how to provide your own event for another class.  It will give you a better idea of how the provider of an event needs to work without too much of the nitty gritty details.